# Scale a AdaptiveIconDrawable (MipMap) Image Asset programatically

Tags: android, android-image

For a bitmap, it is straightforward with the api class Bitmap but I am unsure how to do it for AdaptiveIconDrawable.

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height,
            @Nullable Matrix m, boolean filter) {
```

Comment: file manager displays filenames and their thumbnail images

Comment: doesn't seem to have an effect